# How to insert a draw box with html code in Mechanical Turk?

Tags: html, canvas, mechanicalturk

I am creating a HIT for Mechanical Turk, and I can't (with html code) add a draw box*? It keeps giving me an error "Dhtml template Must contain a question."

*It's a box, like a Microsoft Paint, only with one brush, where the user make a draw by a click drag.

Comment: Do you have any example code that you can post here?

Comment: I can't paste the entire code here, but here's a link to where I was accessing the source that resulted in the error. http://www.matthewtomich.com/flex/drawing/DrawingTool.html

Comment: the app in the link you gave is a flex/flash app, it's not implemented using HTML5 Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This is Adobe Flex mate. (http://www.matthewtomich.com/flex/drawing/srcview/index.html). I thought you were on about HTML.